# jQuery Select Href By Text

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, selector, href

I have the following html:

```
<a href="#DDD">Link here </a>
```

And want to be able to select it by saying get the A tag which has the text "Link Here"

I have tried:

```
    $('a[value="Link here"]')
    $('a :contains("Link here")')
```

But this doesn't work.

Cant seem to see where I am going wrong.

Comment: "get the A tag which has the text "Link Here"" => `:contains` means if element **contains** some text, not meaning if element text **equal** some text. So what are you looking for?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There shouldn't be a space between the tagname and the pseudo selector. A space denotes `:contains("Link here")` is another element, inside `a`, not the same one. You should be using:

```
$('a:contains("Link here")')
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/epb4g/1/)

`:contains` will select an element even if has more than that in the parameters (i.e: 'Link here bla bla bla' would be returned). If you need the text inside to be precisely 'Link here ', you can use `filter()`:

```
$('a').filter(function(){
    return this.innerHTML == 'Link here '; // (Did you know you have a space at the end?)
}).css({background:"#F00"});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/epb4g/2/)

Answer (score 3):

```
$("a.myclass:contains('Text')")
```

this ll work :D